# zsh completion: complete from predefined list

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

My zsh script takes following arguments:

```
./script --connect server --foo 3 --bar 5 name
```

`--foo` and `--bar` take integers, `name` is the only non-option argument, and `--connect` should complete from predefinded list of servers. I am stuck at the `--connect` part, where I tried to define server list.

```
_arguments -S : \
    '--foo' \
    '--bar' \
    '--connect' \
    '*:server:->servers'

_servers() {
    local -a server_list
    server_list=(
        'server1'
        'server2'
    )

    _describe -t server-names "server name" server_list
}
```

it will offer the options, when I type `-<TAB>`, but it does not offer me the servers after `--connect`. Also, I don't know how to incorporate the `name` argument, which is non-option argument.

And I also need to specify that `--foo` and `--bar` need an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a completion script that seems to have the correct behavior. I'm not sure everything is right, and this script can probably be improved.

For example, if all options are required and `name` must be suggested only at the end of all options, then I don't know how to do.

The options are suggested even after `name`, if they wasn't written before it. If you don't want the user to see options suggestions after `name`, then replace line 12 of the script by:

```
'(- :)'':string:->names'
```

Here is the completion script:

```
#compdef script

local state

local -a options_list
options_list=( \
  '(--foo)'--foo'[foo desc]:number:->foos' \
  '(--bar)'--bar'[bar desc]:number:->bars' \
  '(--connect)'--connect'[connect to server]:string:->servers')

_arguments -S : $options_list \
                ':string:->names' \
                && ret=0
  
case $state in

  foos)
    local -a foo_number_list
    foo_number_list=( \
      '80' \
      '8080')
    _values 'Foo (integer)' $foo_number_list \
    && ret=0
  ;;
  
  bars)
    # '-d 123' will indicate 123 as default number:
    _numbers -d 123 'bar number (integer)' \
    && ret=0
  ;;
  
  servers)
    local -a server_lists
    server_lists=( \
      'server1' \
      'server2')
    _values 'Servers' $server_lists \
    && ret=0
  ;;
  
  names)
    _arguments -S : $options_list
    local -a name_list
    name_list=( \
      'name1' \
      'name2')
    _values 'Names' $name_list \
    && ret=0
  ;;
  
esac

return $ret
```